# Joining the 4 digits from the list each time

Tags: python

**I am trying to figure out how do I get the 4 digits each time when I loop back for the data given below**

```
li = ['1','1','7','1','2','1','1','4','1','6','7','8','1','8','1','0','1','B','1','N','1','Y','1','T','1','O']
```

as the output:

```
1171
2114
1678
1810
1B1N
Y1T1
```

Can Anyone help me out please?

Answer I suppose is like this

```
list=['1','2','3','4','5','6','5','4','7','8','9','1','0','6','4','3','4','5','4','7','8','9','0']
j=0
for i in len(list):
     if i%4==0:
         print("\n")
     print(list[i],end=' ')
```

Comment: Did you do any research? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/3001761 seems applicable.

Comment: Where is your attempt?  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `iter` and `zip`:

```
list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(li)]*4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without priting the last 2 values as you show in your output. Using the `step` in the range:

```
li = ['1','1','7','1','2','1','1','4','1','6','7','8','1','8','1','0','1','B','1','N','1','Y','1','T','1','O']
for i in range(0,len(li),4):
    if len(''.join(li[i:i+4])) == 4:
        print(''.join(li[i:i+4]))#+str(li[i+1])+str(li[i+2])+str(li[i+3]))
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

```
1171
2114
1678
1810
1B1N
1Y1T
```